# SSH/RDP remote desktop client

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

Currently, I manage my many SSH/RDP connections with Remmina. I want to find an alternative (regularly, Remmina refuse to save my new connections or new passwords so I have to completely remove and reinstall it). What are my options for alternatives to Remmina (preferably free and opensource) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I was just reading about `teamviewer` today. It seems to bepopular. I use xrdp and openssh, myself, but it depends on what you look for in a provider. I prefer CLI tools, because if they break, it is almost always because you broke them.

Comment: I want a GUI tools to keep a list of connections and to be able to use tabs for multiple connections. And preferably free and opensource. :)

Comment: App recommendation probably off topic here.

Comment: @Antoine liso is right. You should consider changing your question to make it better for the format.  Actually, I think i can change it slightly to get it on track.

Comment: I fixed. No opinion based questions. It needs to have an answer that can be judged equally by anyone, no matter their point of view.  @Antoine

Comment: Thank you @Nate T!

Comment: No problem. Additionally, you may want to add your Ubuntu version and any other relative details. This will make it more likely that you get a good answer.